# Finding average angular velocity, getting a neg answer using my inst. vel. expression. Result ok?

Tags: angular-momentum, acceleration, rotation

I have a two part question that first asked me to find an expression for instantaneous velocity given $\theta=8.5t-15.0t^2+1.6t^4$.

I found that to be $w= 8.5-30.0t+6.4t^3$.

Then the next part was to find the average angular acceleration.

Plugging int 2.0 as $t$ in the equation I found $\alpha$ above I got -0.3 as the answer.

Is it fine that it came out negative or did I do something wrong with the equation or miss something else?

Comment: I would expect to be asked for the average acceleration over a given period of time. What was the given period of time?

Comment: It was between 2 and 3 seconds. I got a non neg answer when plugging in t = 3.

Comment: So you find the angular velocity $w$ at the two times subtract the angular velocity at 2 seconds from the angular velocity at two seconds and divide the answer by 1 which is the time interval to get the average angular acceleration. If $w$ is decreasing during this time interval the angular acceleration will be negative.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm doing. I know the acc. can come out negative, I had just been unsure about  my answer for $w$ being negative for $t=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The average angular acceleration would be the change in the angular velocity divided by the time interval over which the change takes place. The relation you have above is for the instantaneous angular displacement, i.e. angular displacement as a function of time at that point. A negative angular acceleration can be. It's simply the sense in which the angular acceleration is operating.

Though since you're asked to find the *average* angular acceleration, simply plugging in $t$=2.0 in the relation for angular acceleration won't do. The question asks for the *average*, not the instantaneous angular acceleration.